# Store contactform 7 data in to Users - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, authentication, contact-form-7

I'm working on the WordPress website where I want to create the registration form with contact form 7 plugin, users details are stored in the database but unable login to with details which are stored by the contact form 7 plugin into the database?

Any idea how can user login with details which are stored by the contact form 7 plugin?

**Contact Form 7 Form Example**

```
<label>Email (required)
[text* your-email] </label>

<label>Phone(required)
[text* your-phone] </label>

<label>Password(required)
[password* pass] </label>
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: The password you entered for the email address test@yahoo.com 
is incorrect. Lost your password?
```

Comment: by default contact form 7 does not store form details on database. you need to write a hook and get details and store on users table after required validations.

Comment: i'm using contact form 7 addon Frontend Registration - Contact Form 7 which are stored details in the database

Comment: probably there is a misconfiguration, did you set https://ps.w.org/frontend-registration-contact-form-7/trunk/screenshot-1.png?rev=1845222

Comment: You need to store the details in users, user_meta tables

Comment: @dipmala details are stored in the database user_meta but password which is stored in the wp_users table it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code in `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook, please have a look at below completed working code.

```
    add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_form' );

    function save_form( $wpcf7 ) {
            global $wpdb;

            /*
             Note: since version 3.9 Contact Form 7 has removed $wpcf7->posted_data
             and now we use an API to get the posted data.
            */

            $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

            if ( $submission ) {

                $submited = array();                  
                $submited['posted_data'] = $submission->get_posted_data();

             }
         $email=$submited['posted_data']['your-email'];
         $pass=$submited['posted_data']['pass'];
         $userdata = array(
         'user_login'  => $email,  
         'user_email'  => $email,  
         'user_pass'   =>  $pass  // When creating an user, `user_pass` is expected.
         );
         $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;
    }
```

Comment: what is $wpcf7->title()?

Comment: it's not required so remove it, check the answer again